# i cannot make button sort by json in react

Tags: json, reactjs

**i want to have a button and when it is clicked to sort the products by price**

```
  state = {
    products: storeProducts,
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <ProductWrapper className="py-5">
          <div className="container">
            <Title name="our" title="products" />
            <select>
              <option value="price">Price</option>
              <option value="name">Name</option>
            </select>
            <div className="row">
              <ProductConsumer>
                {(value) => {
                  return value.products.map((product) => {
                    return <Product key={product.id} product={product} />;
                  });
                }}
              </ProductConsumer>
            

const ProductWrapper = styled.section``;
```

i tried several ways but nothing worked
https://5f3f90843848e739f77ff21f--react-e-commerce-store-excercise.netlify.app/ here is the website

**here is the data**

```
export const storeProducts = [
 {
   id: 1,
   title: "Samsung 20 plus",
   img: "img/20plus.png",
   price: 1197,
   company: "Samsung",
   info:
     "Lorem ipsum dolor amet offal butcher quinoa sustainable gastropub, echo park actually green gentrify.",
   inCart: false,
   count: 0,
   total: 0,
 },
 {
   id: 2,
   title: "Samsung 20ultra",
   img: "img/20ultra.png",
   price: 1391,
   company: "SAMSUNG",
   info:
     "Lorem ipsum dolor amet offal butcher quinoa sustainable gastropub, echo park actually green juigentrify.",
   inCart: false,
   count: 0,
   total: 0,

 }
```

];

Answer (score 0):

This should help you

```
onClick = () => {
    let newprod_list = this.state.products.sort((a,b) => {
        if (a.price < b.price) return -1;
        if (a.price === b.price) return 0;
        return 1;
    });
    this.setState({products:newprod_list});
}
```

Assign this function to the onClick listener for the button (this sorts in ascending order)

You might wanna edit your render function to something like..

```js
<ProductConsumer>
{this.state.products.map(v => <Product key={v.id} product={v} />)}
</ProductConsumer>
```

Comment: you need `newprod_list ` in `this.setState({products:newprod_list });` not  `this.setState({products:newprod});` right?

Comment: perhaps that last `if (a.price === b.price) return 1;` can just  be `return 1;` since the others are taken care of?

Comment: yeah. it should be `newprod_list` . Sorry for the typo. and yes. it can be just `return 1`.
I did that to make it easy for the reader.
Thanks for the feedback @SafaLabash try the updated edit

Comment: Make sure `this.state.products` is an array. [sort](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) should work on array.